# OpenCV: Merging two images using OpenCV

Tags: .net, image, opencv, image-processing

What is the best way to make the size of  box 2 equal to Box 1 so that CvCopy(); can be applied:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Perhaps I did not put the question properly. So I am re-phrasing it.  Given an Image 2 (as shown above), I want to convert it as shown below:
[image]

Basically I have to add a black border across it. resize will not work as my image will get distorted.  Putting in other words, I have to add zeros in a define thikness around the image.

Also although shown empty, these images(boxes) may have some objects inside them, which I have not shown.

Comment: What's a box and what is wrong with the resize function?

`http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc_geometric_image_transformations.html#resize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `copyMakeBorder` function to do so. I don't know dotnet, below is a sample code in python. Also visit docs for above function : [DOCS](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=cv2.copy#copymakeborder)

First load the two images. `imb` is the big image, and `ims` is the small image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

imb = cv2.imread('messi4.jpg')
ims = cv2.imread('template.jpg')
```

Now let `rb,cb` be the number of rows and columns of big image, and similarly `rs,cs` for small image.

```
rb,cb = imb.shape[:2]
rs,cs = ims.shape[:2]
```

Finally, to use the `copyMakeBorder` function, you need the number of rows and columns to be added at top,bottom,left and right. So we need to find them.

```
top = (rb-rs)/2
bottom = rb - rs - top
left = (cb-cs)/2
right = cb - cs - left
```

Finally apply the function.

```
res = cv2.copyMakeBorder(ims,top,bottom,left,right,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

Now see the results :

**Original Small Image** :

[image]

**Modified New Image** :

[image]

It has the same size of that of my big image ( hasn't shown here, thought it won't be necessary, if you want, i can upload)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the smaller one would not be the best idea as you'll get a lot of image distortion - rather it would be better to shrink the larger one if the final size is not an issue.

You can resize images using `cv::resize( )` (this is the C++ function - I haven't used OpenCV dot net).

Implementation details are  [in the API](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation%29).

In terms of merging, it depends on your definition, but simply using `cv::copy( )` won't do it. There's a full tutorial on image merging [in the documentation, here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html).

Comment: Did you read the link  you sent me? , it says "Warning: Since we are adding src1 and src2, they both have to be of the same size (width and height) and type". Also re-size is of no use to me, as it will distort the image.

Comment: I am aware of that. Your original question implied that you wanted to resize one to the same size as the other then merge.