# I want know the best way to subtract background image in java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, marvin-framework

title is my question!
i tried opencv and Marvin library but all of these are failed because i couldn't know how to use..
so i want to know what is the best way to subtract background image in java.

if you hava some example using opencv, could you share for me?
or how to use Marvin in eclipse? i tried to add marvin library, but failed...

Comment: Please show what you tried and what the results were for each attempt. Also explain in more detail what you want to do. Give an example input and show our describe the desired results.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#absdiff and threshold afterwards, then mask the image.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net), take a look at the [MergePhotos](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/plugins/mergePhotos.html) plug-in. This  plug-in need to construct the background model to merge the photos.

It was already discussed on Stack Overflow:
[how to merge Images and impose on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298646/how-to-merge-images-and-impose-on-each-other/19388602#19388602)

The plug-in [source code](https://github.com/gabrielarchanjo/marvinproject/blob/master/marvinproject/dev/MarvinPlugins/src/org/marvinproject/image/combine/mergePhotos/MergePhotos.java) demonstrates how to use another plug-in: **DetermineSceneBackground**. This last plug-in can be used to construct the background model or you can check the [source code](https://github.com/gabrielarchanjo/marvinproject/blob/master/marvinproject/dev/MarvinPlugins/src/org/marvinproject/image/background/determineSceneBackground/DetermineSceneBackground.java) and use it to develop your own approach.